# how to download webpage with flash content

Tags: flash, download, wget

I have been using wget to download some webpages:

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p URL
```

The above command works well for HTML, CSS, and images, but not Flash. Is there a way with wget to also download embedded Flash files? Or with some other open source tool?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is very interesting question but i give all solution for flash problem

if you show a content form other site like youtube then you use his javascript api
if you download video form youtube then use Firefox extension " Easy video downloader"

if you download a Flash content then adobe flash player not give a permission for download
so you can download by this technique

if you use Microsoft winfdow then go to C: & Document & Setting & Click your Current user name folder & Click on local settings & choose Temprery Internet Files folder you can see some flash content so you move it by using explorer bar ok

if you learn more about it contact me @ anirudhakumar.gupta@gmail.com
please give me vote 
thanks for saying a interesting question

Comment: I am looking for an automated solution that I can program

Comment: seems that video sites intentionally make it difficult to download their content so there is no general solution besides using a tool like you suggest